# get a configure variable in a post install script to a package .deb

Tags: linux, configure, dpkg

I have the source code that produces a .deb with the command `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b`.

I want to run the installed software chrooted, so I added an option --prefix to the debian/rules configuration file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh ${@} --with autotools_dev,autoreconf

override_dh_auto_configure:
        dh_auto_configure -- \
                        --prefix=/usr/share/chroot-dir \
                        --libdir=\$${prefix}/lib \
                        --without-kernel-modules \
                        --without-x \
                        --without-procps \
                        CFLAGS="-Wno-deprecated-declarations $(CFLAGS)" \
                        CUSTOM_PROCPS_NAME=procps

override_dh_auto_install:
        dh_auto_install -- DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/open-vm-tools

override_dh_builddeb:
        dh_builddeb -- -Zxz

override_dh_fixperms:
        dh_fixperms -Xsbin/mount.vmhgfs

override_dh_installinit:
        dh_installinit --update-rcd-params='start 38 2 3 4 5 . stop 38 0 1 6 .'

override_dh_strip:
        dh_strip --dbg-package=open-vm-tools-dbg
```

But in order to run the chrooted program, I need to add librairies to the directory, which is automated with a script. Is there a way I can share a global variable between rules and postinst?